# Disabling intent to call

Tags: android

I have a webview that loads a html page saved in the assets folder of my android application. I have some phone numbers that when tapped I wouldn't want a call activity call invoked. I thought editing the activity permissions in the manifest would help, but that's long winded.

Comment: what do you expect to happen when tap/touch/click phone number ? may you show us code .. this will be helpful

Comment: This is in a (</br>0xxxxxx 68 29 58<br>
</br>From overseas: +44 xxxx 51<br>) .html page this is loaded and displayed by the webview using webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/xxx.html"); Now when the number is tapped I DON'T want the phone dialer to start up

Answer (score 0):

well, try to override URL and in case it cause calling , so return true or any thing else .. to do you will need to create an extended class from WebViewClient and set it in webview:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webv);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new ImWebViewClient());  
//.....
    }

class ImWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   //check the url and when it will come with your phone number return true ..
   if(url!=null && url.contain("123456789"))
       return true;
   return false;//means apply other mime type if available, and this may by default cause calling your number...
     }
}
```